# Any way to reduce the Fermi-Dirac EEDF to Maxwell-Boltzmann?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics

I just read an article which confused me somehow (B. Deschaud et al 2014 EPL 108 53001)

The author claims that for very high temperatures the electron energy distribution function becomes the classical [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution for energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution#Distribution_for_the_energy).

Note that I'm talking about 
$$F_{FD}(E)=\frac{2}{(2\pi)^2 n_e} \left(\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}\right)^{3/2}\sqrt{E} \times \frac{1}{1+e^{(E-\mu)/kT}} $$
and that
$$F_{MB}(E)=2\sqrt{E/\pi} (kT)^{-3/2} e^{-E/kT}$$
I do see how the Fermi-Dirac distribution becomes Maxwellian for the high temperature or low-density case but what about the density of states?

Is there some smart series expansion which get's me there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that for Maxwellian electrons the chemical potential may be written as

$$\mu/kT=\ln(n_e \Lambda^3/2) $$

with the thermal De-Broglie wavelength

$$\Lambda=\left(\frac{2 \pi \hbar^2}{m_e k T} \right) $$

This makes the FD-EEDF indeed become the MB-EEDF.

Comment: There is an important typo in the answer of OP IUM, it should be: $ \mu $/ kT = ln(n$_e$ $\Lambda$^${\frac{3}{2}}$) Also seen from here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/670836/chemical-potential-of-ideal-gas-from-canonical-ensemble